# Qt: Align Text Center and Left using StyleSheet

Tags: c++, qt

I want to align the text in a QLabel in such a way that horizontal alignment is left and vertical alignment is center with word-wrap. Currently I am doing something like this

```css
QLabel
{
    qproperty-alignment: AlignLeft;
}
```

I want to know how I can set text vertical and horizontal alignment individually.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most likely you should write something like:

```
 qproperty-alignment: 'AlignVCenter | AlignLeft';
 qproperty-wordWrap: true;
```

Comment: Sorry for fixing the answer a couple of times, it's me being absent-minded.

Comment: I am doing `qproperty-alignment: 'AlignLeft | AlignCenter';` and thats not helping

Comment: @MistyD Oh sorry apparently it should be `AlignVCenter`